# Oracle how to grab columns for just one index?

Tags: sql, oracle, key

I am using the following query to grab the index columns on a table along with their data type:

```
SELECT DISTINCT COL.COLUMN_NAME, COL.DATA_TYPE 
FROM DBA_IND_COLUMNS IND
  INNER JOIN DBA_TAB_COLUMNS COL
    ON ( IND.TABLE_OWNER = COL.OWNER AND IND.TABLE_NAME = COL.TABLE_NAME        
AND IND.COLUMN_NAME = COL.COLUMN_NAME)
WHERE IND.TABLE_NAME = 'MY_TABLE' AND TABLE_OWNER = 'SCHEMA'
```

But how can I grab the columns for just one index, instead of the columns for all the indexes?

For example:
If a table has indexes:

INDEX1: column_a,column_b
INDEX2: column_c,column_d

My current query would result in:

```
column_a, varchar
column_b, varchar
column_c, varchar
column_d, varchar
```

but I want it to result in just:

```
column_a, varchar
column_b, varchar
```

Comment: What do you mean by _just one index_? Do you want the columns only for the first index?

Comment: @MarceloVinícius yes, sorry I was not clear enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you just want the columns for the first index (in alphabetical order), you can try:

```
SELECT DISTINCT COL.COLUMN_NAME, COL.DATA_TYPE 
FROM DBA_IND_COLUMNS IND
    INNER JOIN DBA_TAB_COLUMNS COL
    ON ( IND.TABLE_OWNER = COL.OWNER AND IND.TABLE_NAME = COL.TABLE_NAME        
AND IND.COLUMN_NAME = COL.COLUMN_NAME)
WHERE IND.TABLE_NAME = 'MY_TABLE' AND TABLE_OWNER = 'SCHEMA'
AND INDEX_NAME = 
(
    SELECT MIN(INDEX_NAME) 
    FROM DBA_IND_COLUMNS IIND
    INNER JOIN DBA_TAB_COLUMNS CCOL
    ON ( IIND.TABLE_OWNER = CCOL.OWNER AND IIND.TABLE_NAME = CCOL.TABLE_NAME )       
)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need columns in the first index of the table, try filtering with a subquery:

```
SELECT DISTINCT COL.COLUMN_NAME, COL.DATA_TYPE 
FROM DBA_IND_COLUMNS IND
  INNER JOIN DBA_TAB_COLUMNS COL
    ON ( IND.TABLE_OWNER = COL.OWNER AND IND.TABLE_NAME = COL.TABLE_NAME        
AND IND.COLUMN_NAME = COL.COLUMN_NAME)
WHERE IND.TABLE_NAME = 'MY_TABLE' AND TABLE_OWNER = 'SCHEMA'
  AND INDEX_NAME = (SELECT MIN(INDEX_NAME)
                       FROM DBA_IND_COLUMNS IND2
                      WHERE     IND2.TABLE_NAME = IND.TABLE_NAME
                            AND IND2.TABLE_OWNER = IND.TABLE_OWNER)
```

This can even be re-written with some analytic function.

Comment: thank you, but is there a way to select the columns for an index without knowing the index name before hand?

Comment: I can't understand your need; without knowing the index name, how would you choose the index to show? The first alphabetically, based on the number of columns, ... Can you post an example please

Comment: @Aleksej He specified in a comment that he wanted the columns only for the first (alphabetically, I assume) index. If my assumption is correct, check my answer.

Comment: @Marcelo Thanks, just edited. Your solution seems to extract only one column of the first index, not all the columns